# How to load geojson data from html file input?

Tags: javascript, file, leaflet, geojson

I want to build the system that allows the client to upload the geojson files from html form and this data will show on the leaflet map. While I try to do so, It shows the error code 405. I want to submit the form containing geojson file and load this file using leaflet-omnivore plugin.

My html file as,

```
    <section class="addVectorLayer">
        <form action="" method="POST" class="vector">
            Click to add your vector layer. It support Json, Geojson, csv, gpx and kml formats.
            <input type="file" name="files" id="input_files">
        </form>
    </section>
```

my js file is here,

```
    geojson.onlode = function() {
    geojson.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('input_files').files[0]);
    };
    omnivore.geojson(geojson.result).addTo(map);
```

#### Edit

Sorry This is not the duplicated one. In this question, I want to read the geojson file using omnivore leaflet-plugin.

Comment: Sorry! this is not the duplicated one. I don't want the async call. I want to read the geojson file using omnivore plugin